# How can I change a text field to date/time for calculating duration

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to calculate the duration of time from the start field to the end field from a dbo_table. I'm pulling the table from my scheduling software so I have no control over the formatting. The text formatted fields are entered as "09:00" and "15:30" to correspond to 9:00am and 3:30pm. I need to some how convert them into time so that they can be mathematically summed to achieve the duration of time. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CDate` to convert to *Date*, then subtract:

```vb
Duration = CDate(CDate([TimeEnd]) - CDate([TimeStart]))
```

The duration you can format as *time* using the format `h:nn`.

Comment: _.. until the field is changed from TEXT to DATE_. Yes, and that's exactly what `CDate` does. `DateValue` ignores a time part; if you don't like `CDate`, use `TimeValue`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, needed to change a couple other things to make it work, but we are off and running. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Try DateDiff() function with the text data. Access should automatically cast to date/time. Example:

`DateDiff("n","09:00","15:30")`

returns 390 minutes.

This does assume time range is in same day.